# How to tell if a server running Windows Server 2016, which you're accessing via Windows RDC, is virtual or real?

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

How can you tell if a Windows 2016 Server you're accessing via RDC is a virtual machine?

Comment: @Michael Hampton:  Those answers are from 5 or more  years ago and do not relate to Windows Server 2016. Do I gather from your marking the question as a duplicate that you are saying that nothing has changed in the interim?

Comment: Nothing has changed in the interim.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of options here. A favorite of mine is to look at the hardware model information on the C: drive if I'm feeling lazy.

If I'm using PowerShell,  `( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem ).Model`

Comment: Thanks. What Model value indicates a virtual machine?

Comment: "VMware Virtual Platform" is one option for a VMWare Virtual Machine

Comment: @Tim Liston: Is the ONLY thing one needs to look for one of those VM strings?   Are there other kinds of virtual machines that wouldn't have "VMWare..."?  I am hoping to find a single definitive way of identifying whether it's actual or virtual.